# SimpleDB with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-simpledb

Are there any good tutorials to learn basics of SimpleDB with Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Amazon SimpleDB with Ruby on Rails** 
http://www.slideshare.net/martin.rehfeld/amazon-simple-db-07-feb-2008-rug-b

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial Learn Rails by Example Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two?version=2.3#top)
This is one of great tutorial that any new comer can follow. It's have some great examples that we can easily understand.